# how to send multiple records in single http request and how to receive in the other end in android?

Tags: android, http, rest

In my android application multiple records should be updated to Mysql database. 
I can able to it for single record but stuck in updating the multiple records. 
below is my code for sending single record how to do it for multiple records.

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("appname", appName));
nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("start_time", startTime));
nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("end_time", endTime));
 try{

     HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.24/file_data_insert.php");
     httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
     HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
     HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity(); 
     is = entity.getContent();
    }
catch(Exception e){
     Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString())
}
```

Comment: so i think you need to track last record number in shared pref so when you fetch second time it will update from next

Comment: or take some constant so it will increment.

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap your database  with  rest service ( say with CXF,  pico web remoting, whatever you prefer )  and return JSON document from it.  It can be parsed to objects easily